# Cannot overwrite existing keybinding Shift+k in Neovim

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

I want to map <kbd>Shift-k</kbd> (K) as `5k` but it is mapped to call a function `vim.lsp.buf.hover()`

These commands dont work:

```
map <S-k> 5k  
nmap <S-k> 5k  
noremap <S-k> 5k  
nnoremap <S-k> 5k
```

Replacing `<S-k>` with `<S-K>` or `K` doesn't work.

`:map K` shows this:

```
n  K           *@<Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a `<buffer>` mapping that hides your mapping.

I would do:

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <S-k> 5k
```

Or if you want to do for all the buffers

```
:silent! bufdo nunmap <buffer> <S-k>
:nnoremap <S-k> 5k
```

*Remark: The `@` sign indicate that the mapping is buffer mapping.*

More information about this with: `:help map-listing`.

Comment: This works only on that buffer where it run this command. adding it to init.lua doesnt help, have to source it in the buffer manually.

Comment: I have adapted the solution to make sure the corresponding `<buffer>` is deleted from all the open buffers. If you want to use it in your configuration you should probably set your mapping in an autocmd that is set after the autocmd that sets the `<S-k>` mapping.